# How do I define a datetime field in sqlx rust

Tags: rust

I have a struct as follows?

```
pub struct Instrument {
  pub id:i32,
  pub expiry_on: <this should be a date field>
}
```

What should I give the type of `expiry_on`. I want to use the struct inside `sqlx::query_as!()` to fetch records from `postgres` ?

`expiry_on` is a `timestampz` `Postgres` field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Under the assumption that your expiry_on field in postgres is a `timestamptz`: Depending on the time library you use, you will either want to add the `chrono` feature or the `time` feature to sqlx. Which you can do in `Cargo.toml` like this:

```
[dependencies]
sqlx = { version = "*", features = [ "chrono" ] }
```

or

```
sqlx = { version = "*", features = [ "time" ] }
```

instead of

```
sqlx = "*"
```

Where `*` is whatever version you're using.

You then change the following in Instrument (assuming `chrono`):

```rust
pub struct Instrument {
    pub id: i32,
    pub expiry_on: chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>,
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite right - the traits serialize and deserialize are not implemented for chrono.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the [answer by izik1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61670747/2193620), we can enable chrono's serde support feature as follows:

```ini
chrono = { version = "0.4.24", features = ["serde"] }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to summarize how to do this:

```
# Cargo.toml:
[dependencies]
# get all required types
chrono = { version = "0.4.*", features = ["serde"] }
# enable sqlx-conversion traits for chrono-types
sqlx = { version = "0.6.*", features = [ "chrono",...] }
```

after importing, do the following:

```
pub struct Instrument {
    pub id: i32,
    # important: import from chrono-crate!
    pub expiry_on: chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>, 
}
```